# What happens when data is written into a memory location which is pointed by a dangling pointer of a different data type

Tags: c++, dangling-pointer

If pointer data type is same as the newly entered data,i guess it wouldn't give an error,but if the pointer has a different data type ,we'll have a type mismatch. I was wondering whether the compiler would do something about it(say delete the dangling pointer first),or simply give an error.

Comment: Anything could happen.

Comment: ... including nothing at all.

Comment: Without a specific case this is too broad. Answers will probably end up listing how many things could go wrong.

Comment: The same thing happens as when you write via a dangling pointer of the *correct* data type: undefined behavior.

Answer (score 0):

@YuHao is absolutely right.

If you `delete` first, you might get a segmentation fault, if that unmaps a page that previously existed in your process' address space.

In any other case, you just write data somewhere; there might be useful stuff there by the time you do that, there might not. At any rate, you must avoid this.

Answer (score 0):

> I was wondering whether the compiler would do something about it(say delete the dangling pointer first)

Could do (won't)

> or simply give an error.

Could do (won't)

It's a dangling pointer. There's no protection against that.

It's **undefined behaviour**. This is fundamentally unanswerable.

Comment: If it's unanswerable, how's that you posted an answer? :P

Comment: @KarolyHorvath: Shush

Comment: (won't). "There's no protection against that." - surely there's, just nobody does it, it's too expensive.

Comment: @KarolyHorvath: If nobody does protection, how's it that there's protection? :P

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps a quick overview so we are on the same page will help.

Let's assume a modern PC with a multi-tasking OS like Linux.

When a C++ program is run, a process is created that has a private memory space. This is a linear mapping of addresses that get translated by the CPU and OS to real addresses in RAM.

C++ is a strongly typed, low-level language with manual memory management. Strongly typed means the compiler does some basic checks to make sure logical statements in your program make sense. Pointers are just another type.

For instance:

```
float f = 10.0f; // this is ok, 10.0f is a float literal
float* pF = &f;   // types match, & operator returns type float*
int i = f;        // types do not match. Compiler error or warning. 
int* i = pF;      // types do not match, int* is not float*
float f2 = pF;    // types do not match, float is not float*
```

and so on.

Thats's compile time. That's really it. Once the program is running, the C++ runtime is pretty dumb. It doesn't do too many checks on memory operations since those can slow a program down and C++'s philosophy is "if you didn't ask for it, you don't pay for it".

At it the most fundamental our memory is just a sequence of bytes. Data types like float and int are multi-byte data types (4 bytes for 32-bit platforms). That means a float in memory is stored in 4 adjacent byte-sized slots.

Finally, we are ready to answer your question. If you allocate memory at runtime through something like `new` you are handed back a pointer to memory you can use. Say we do this for a single float. `new` knows how to mark that memory as "in use". `new` won't give a pointer to those 4 bytes to anyone else, so you are safe. When you invoke `delete` that gives the memory back to the heap - some other part of your program is free to allocate it later. But the *pointer* you have is unmodified. We can still use the pointer to write to memory, only now we are headed for trouble.

Example:

```
float *pF = new float; // allocate 4-bytes on a 32-bit system
*pF = 10.0f;           // fine
delete pF;             // free the memory
*pF = 20.0f;           // ?????
```

That last instruction says "write 20.0f to the memory pointed to by pF". We don't "own" that memory any longer. We say this pointer is dangling as it doesn't point to valid memory we can write to safely. But it does point to writable memory. You are correct that this is a source of bugs.

There are C++ memory allocators that will write special values into memory to indicate whether it is uninitialized or previously deleted. This will depend on your OS and toolset.

Another option to find bugs like this is to use the awesome tool [Valgrind](http://valgrind.org) which will simulate your program memory and flag these kinds of bugs.